# How to print Lego bricks?

Tags: 3d-models, resin, legal, elegoo-mars, bricks

How can I print Lego bricks in order to make them attach?

I need them to be standalone pieces. I use resin to print. My model is Elegoo Mars 3. What resolution should I use?

Also, how should I color the bricks? I have some colored resin at home but I want to make them all black and color them afterward.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't print a LEGO<sup>TM</sup> Brick, because you are not Lego System A/S.** The best you can do is print a brick that is *compatible* with LEGO<sup>TM</sup> bricks. Also note that Lego Systems A/S has more than 600 US design patents, which might interfere with the legality of manufacturing bricks in the US.

The original bricks are made from ABS and made with a *very* tight tolerance and uses the inherent flexibility of the material to create a friction fit. However, Resin prints do lack the required mix of sturdyness and flexibility and thus can't create the required friction fit.

In other words: You can't make bricks that are compatible with LEGO<sup>TM</sup> bricks with a resin printer based on the material properties.

Comment: Given that OP seems to want to use a coating for color already, could it work to do resin prints with additional clearance allowing for additional thickness from the coating to provide the needed flexibility and friction fit?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE no. the coating would just get destroyed over time.

Comment: The main patent on Legos has been expired since the 90’s, I remember when all these knockoffs were hitting the market. Also US patent law does not prohibit an individual from making a clone for their own personal use.

Comment: Design patents are different.